# "run time templates"

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I'm pretty sure the answer is "you can't use templates, you have to use virtual functions (dynamic polymorphism)", but it seems like I'd have to duplicate a lot of code if I went that route. Here is the setup:

I currently have two classes, ColorImageSegmentation and GrayscaleImageSegmentation. They do essentially the same thing, but there are three differences
- they operate on different types (ColorImage and GrayscaleImage) 
- a parameter, the dimensionality of the histogram (3 vs 1) is different
- The PixelDifference function is different based on the image type

If I create a class

```
template <TImageType>
class ImageSegmentation
{
};
```

I would be in good shape. However, I want to have this object as a member of another class:

```
class MyMainClass
{
 ImageSegmentation MyImageSegmentation;
};
```

But the user needs to determine the type of `MyImageSegmentation` (if the user opens a grayscale image, I want to instantiate `MyImageSegmentation<GrayScaleType>`. Likewise for a color image, `MyImageSegmentation<ColorType>`.)

With derived classes, I could store a pointer and then do:

```
class MyMainClass
{
 ImageSegmentation* MyImageSegmentation;
};

... user does something...
MyImageSegmentation = new ColorImageSegmentation;
```

but how would I do something like this with templates? The problem is I have a lot of:

```
typedef TImageType::HistogramType HistogramType;
typedef TImageType::PixelType PixelType;
```

sort of things going on, so I don't know how I would convert them to the dynamic polymorphic model without duplicating a whole bunch of code.

Sorry for the rambling... does anyone have any suggestions for me?

Thanks,

David

Comment: Please edit the question to properly format the code samples.

Comment: Boost's GIL (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html) does the same thing. You can check how did they solve that problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe there are additional requirements you haven't told us about, but from what you have so far, you can pass the type down through the containing class:

```
template<typename TImage>
class MyMainClass
{
   ImageSegmentation<TImage> MyImageSegmentation;
};
```

Most likely you'll need some layer of dynamic dispatch, but only at the highest level of abstraction:

```
struct IMainClass
{
   virtual bool SaveToFile(std::string filename) = 0;
   virtual bool ApplySharpenFilter(int level) = 0;
   ...
};

template<typename TImage>
class MyMainClass : public IMainClass
{
   ImageSegmentation<TImage> MyImageSegmentation;
public:
   virtual bool SaveToFile(std::string filename);
   virtual bool ApplySharpenFilter(int level);
};

IMainClass* pMain = new MyMainClass<GrayscaleImage>();
```

Comment: +1: Make a common base class, then derive from it with a templated class.

Comment: What is the point of even making the IMainClass hold anything? It can just be empty, and then the real templated class can derive from it. This still allows the 
IMainClass* pMain = new MyMainClass<GrayscaleImage>();
which is exactly what I was looking for. Right?

Comment: It doesn't "hold" anything.  It's an abstract imagetype-independent interface for the UI (or whatever is controlling the images) to keep track of a current image.  After all, your "Sharpen" menu item (if this is a photoshop clone) has to affect the active file, and has to do so for a myriad of file types.

Comment: @David: wrt to your second comment, if you make that base class empty, then yes you can write `IMainClass* pMain = new MyMainClass<GrayscaleImage>();` but you can't DO anything with that pointer.

Comment: Oh right, right, I won't be able to call the functions on the IMainClass pointer if they aren't declared in IMainClass.

Comment: Ben, what about my SetImage(TImageType* image) function? I can't declare it in the IMainClass because I don't know the type until I get to MyMainClass. However, I need to call this function on the IMainClass pointer.

Comment: @David: Can you make that a parameter to the `MyMainClass<T>` constructor?  When you first create the object, you know it's exact type and can call specific functions.  It's only when you store it into that `IMainClass*` variable that you lose the specific type.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a templated version of your objects but have those objects take different parameter types based on the templated parameter?  That's not a very easy thing to integrate into a library but there are a few ways of going about it.

Take a look at [unary_function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/unary_function/) for inspiration.  There they are using templated traits to carry around the type parameters without having to work any sort of magic:

```
template <class Arg, class Result>
  struct unary_function {
    typedef Arg argument_type;
    typedef Result result_type;
  };
```

'unary_function' does not contain any functionality other than declaring typedefs.  These typedefs, however, allow you to express in code and at compile time named equivalents between code segments.  They leverage the way template parameters are checked.

What this means is that you can have objects that work on this:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo{
    typedef typename T::argument_type argument_type;
    Foo(T _myFunc) : m_Func(_myFunc)
    void myWrappedFunction(argument_type _argument){ m_Func( _argument ); }
};
```

which contains within it the value type of the arguments without having to specify them in advance.  So if you have `pixel_type` or something similar for each of your image objects then simply stating `typename T::pixel_type` will call forward the type parameter you need.

Comment: wheaties, thanks for the reply. I don't how see this allows T to be set at runtime though? In fact, the library I'm using already does this, I just need to specify T at runtime so that things like T::argument_type will be the right type.